# What is the application of pure vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The concept of "orthonormal basis" in my linear algebra textbook is introduced directly in the context of "vector space". But I think it needs the additional structure defined on the vector space. We cannot talk about "orthonormal" without inner-product. Am I right?

Further more, I cannot imagine the real usage of vector space without any additional structure: No norm, no inner-product, no length, no degree. We only have linear combination. Is there some important theorems on pure vector space or normed vector space? If no, why don't we define like "vector space must have inner-product"?

Comment: [Banach spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_space) are important in functional analysis. They don't generally have inner product structure. Sometimes people discuss [topological vector spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_vector_space) that have even less structure..

Comment: In a real vector space, it is always possible to define an inner-product.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Do you mean that real vector space is always inner-product space? Is the define of inner-product unique on it?

Comment: @ShenLei Consider a basis $(e_i)_{i \in I}$ of your vector space. Then $\langle x \mid y \rangle = \sum\limits_{i\in I} e_i^*(x)e_i^*(y)$ defines an inner-product (for which the basis is orthonormal). Of course the inner product is not unique, I am sure you know spaces where you have lots of different inner-products.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe  That is only true for **finite dimensional** vector spaces.

Comment: @user247327 Why ? The construction of the inner product also works in infinite dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, a vector space must also have an inner product before the concept of an orthonormal basis makes sense (and if the vector space is infinite dimensional there are other technical requirements as well - it needs to be either separable or complete). A vector space with an inner product is called an [inner product space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space).

However, vector spaces without inner products are still useful in their own right. For example, the solutions to a system of linear equations form a vector space, as do the solutions to a system of linear differential equations.